# Fragment management access error visible return false

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I am managing the fragment as show and hide.
But when I try to access the method in one fragment, I get null and I ask the question.
Of course, method access works well in other fragments that manage the same.

This is my hide code.

```
private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            if (fragment.isAdded) {
                show(fragment)
            } else {
                add(R.id.container_activity_main, fragment)
            }

            supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
                if (it != fragment && it.isAdded) {
                    hide(it)
                }
            }
        }.commit()
    }
```

my show code

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentName).commit()
```

fragmentName is arbitrarily specified for the question

If you take a log of the codes below, false, false, and true are displayed.

```
${fragmentName!!.isVisible}, ${fragmentName!!.isDetached} ,${fragmentName!!.userVisibleHint}
```

Here the fragment is visible to me but isVisible always return false .
I don't know why this happens.

Even if onStop is called in hide , if you show, onCreateView is called and there should be a view, but the view becomes null and the app does not work.

I don't know why this is happening.
The view is visible, but visible returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the visibility issue you should use :

```
     fragment.userVisibleHint
```

instead of:

```
     fragment.isVisible
```

Like mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()).

Fragment.isVisible doesn't work with all fragment use cases, it can be true only if fragment.isAdded == true, fragment.isHidden == false, fragment.view != null, fragment.view.windowToken != null and fragment.view.visibility == View.VISIBLE.
Only if all these conditions are met in your implementation of the fragment, then the isVisible method returns true.

Comment: My question is why does fragment.isVisible return false

Comment: understand. Are you saying that even if the screen is visible, false is returned if any one of them is false?

Comment: @Duseop Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

**commit()** is an asynchronous method and will be finished at a later moment. If you output your logs right after the commit - the operation might not be finished yet

Comment: Even if you don't print it out right away, it comes out like that. I already pulled out the log every 10 seconds after the screen was displayed, but it's still like that.